# How to make a mouse click do something at a specific point?

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

how can I make the mouse do something once it's clicking at a certain point in Zelle's graphics? What I am trying to do is make my stopwatch start when I click the "startbutton" image. However, I am obviously doing something wrong because my program either crashes or doesn't do anything.

```
from graphics import *
import time
#from tkinter import *

win = GraphWin('Stopwatch', 600, 600)
win.yUp()

#Assigning images
stopWatchImage = Image(Point (300, 300), "stopwatch.png")
startImage = Image(Point (210, 170), "startbutton.png")
stopImage = Image(Point (390, 170), "stopbutton.png")
lapImage = Image(Point (300, 110), "lapbutton.png")


stopWatchImage.draw(win)
startImage.draw(win)
stopImage.draw(win)
lapImage.draw(win)


sec = 0
minute = 0
hour = 0

def isBetween(x, end1, end2):
'''Return True if x is between the ends or equal to either.
The ends do not need to be in increasing order.'''

    return end1 <= x <= end2 or end2 <= x <= end1

def isInside(point, startImage):
'''Return True if the point is inside the Rectangle rect.'''

    pt1 = startImage.getP1()
    pt2 = startImage.getP2()
    return isBetween(point.getX(), pt1.getX(), pt2.getX()) and \
           isBetween(point.getY(), pt1.getY(), pt2.getY())


def getChoice(win):     #NEW
'''Given a list choicePairs of tuples with each tuple in the form
(rectangle, choice), return the choice that goes with the rectangle
in win where the mouse gets clicked, or return default if the click
is in none of the rectangles.'''

    point = win.getMouse()
    if isInside(point, startImage):
        time.sleep(1)
        sec += 1
        timeText.setText(sec)
        timeText.setText('')


        while sec >= 0 and sec < 61:

         #Displaying Time
            timeText = Text(Point (300,260), str(hour) + ":" + str(minute) + ":" + str(sec))
            timeText.setSize(30)
            timeText.draw(win)
            time.sleep(1)
            sec += 1
            timeText.setText(sec)
            timeText.setText('')
            #Incrementing minutes,hours
            if sec == 60:
                sec = 0        
                minute += 1

            if minute == 60:
                sec = 0
                minute = 0
                hour += 1


return default


def layout()
    getChoice(win)

layout()
```

I can't seem to get it to work.

Edit: added the rest of my code for clarification.

Comment: edit question, highlight code and use button `{}` to correctly format code. Now you have wrong indentions.

Comment: I have edited the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setMouseHandler` to assign function which will called when you click in window.

In example if you click in left part of window then it draws rectangle, if you click in right part of window then it draws circle.

You can open file `graphics.py` and see all code. It is the fastest method to can see what functions you can use.

```
from graphics import *

# --- functions ---

def on_click(point):
    # inform function to use global variable
    global win

    if point.x > win.width//2:
        c = Circle(point, 10)
        c.draw(win)
    else:
        a = Point(point.x - 10, point.y - 10)
        b = Point(point.x + 10, point.y + 10)
        r = Rectangle(a, b)
        r.draw(win)

def main():
    # inform function to use global variable
    global win

    win = GraphWin("My Circle", 500, 500)

    win.setMouseHandler(on_click)

    win.getKey() 
    win.close()

# --- start ---

# create global variable
win = None

main()
```

---

**BTW:** `graphics` uses `Tkinter` which has widgets `Button`, `Label`, `Text`, etc. It can use `canvas.create_window()` to add widget to canvas.

`Tkinter` has also function `after(miliseconds, function_name)` which lets you execute function periodically - ie. to update time.

Example

```
from graphics import *
import datetime

# --- classes ---

class _Widget():
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, **options):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.options = options

    def draw(self, canvas, **options):
        return None

    def set(self, **options):
        self.widget.config(options)

    def get(self, **options):
        self.widget.cget(options)

class Button(_Widget):

    def draw(self, canvas, **options):
        x, y = canvas.toScreen(self.x, self.y) # ???

        self.widget = tk.Button(canvas, self.options)

        return canvas.create_window((x, y), options, width=self.w, height=self.h, window=self.widget, anchor='nw')

class Label(_Widget):

    def draw(self, canvas, **options):
        x, y = canvas.toScreen(self.x, self.y) # ???

        self.widget = tk.Label(canvas, self.options)

        return canvas.create_window((x, y), options, width=self.w, height=self.h, window=self.widget, anchor='nw')

# --- functions ---

def on_start():
    #global b1, b2
    global running

    b1.set(state='disabled')
    b2.set(state='normal')

    running = True

    # run first time
    update_time()

    print("START")

def on_stop():
    #global b1, b2
    global running

    b1.set(state='normal')
    b2.set(state='disabled')
    l.set(text="Controls:")

    running = False

    print("STOP")

def update_time():
    #global l
    #global running

    if running:

        l.set(text=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

        # run again after 1000ms (1s)
        win.after(1000, update_time)

# --- main ---

def main():
    global win, l, b1, b2

    win = GraphWin("My Buttons", 500, 500)

    l = Label(0, 0, 100, 50, text="Controls:")
    l.draw(win)

    b1 = Button(100, 0, 100, 50, text="START", command=on_start)
    b1.draw(win)

    b2 = Button(200, 0, 100, 50, text="STOP", command=on_stop, state='disabled')
    b2.draw(win)

    win.getKey() 
    win.close()

# --- global variable to access in functions ---

win = None
l  = None
b1 = None
b2 = None

running = False

# --- start ---

main()
```

Tkinter: [Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm), [Button](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm), [other](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm#class-reference)

---

**EDIT:**  working example

```
from graphics import *


def isBetween(x, end1, end2):
    return end1 <= x <= end2 or end2 <= x <= end1

def isInside(point, startImage):
    x = startImage.getAnchor().getX()
    y = startImage.getAnchor().getY()
    w = startImage.getWidth()/2
    h = startImage.getHeight()/2

    pt1_x = x - w
    pt1_y = y - h

    pt2_x = x + w
    pt2_y = y + h

    return isBetween(point.getX(), pt1_x, pt2_x) and \
           isBetween(point.getY(), pt1_y, pt2_y)


def getChoice(event):
    global hour, minute, sec
    global running

    point = Point(round(event.x), round(event.y))

    if isInside(point, startImage):
        sec = 0
        minute = 0
        hour = 0
        running = True
        update_time()

    if isInside(point, stopImage):
        running = False


def update_time():
    global hour, minute, sec
    #global timeText
    #global win

    sec += 1

    if sec == 60:
        sec = 0        
        minute += 1
        if minute == 60:
            minute = 0
            hour += 1

    timeText.setText('{}:{}:{}'.format(hour, minute, sec))

    if running:
        win.after(1000, update_time)
    else:
        timeText.setText('')


def layout():
    global win
    global stopWatchImage
    global startImage
    global stopImage
    global lapImage
    global timeText

    win = GraphWin('Stopwatch', 600, 600)
    #win.yUp()

    #Assigning images
    stopWatchImage = Image(Point(300, 300), "stopwatch.png")
    startImage = Image(Point(210, 170), "startbutton.png")
    stopImage = Image(Point(390, 170), "stopbutton.png")
    lapImage = Image(Point(300, 110), "lapbutton.png")

    #Drawing images
    stopWatchImage.draw(win)
    startImage.draw(win)
    stopImage.draw(win)
    lapImage.draw(win)

    timeText = Text(Point(300,260), '')
    timeText.setSize(30)
    timeText.draw(win)

    win.setMouseHandler(getChoice)

    win.getKey()

# --- global variable ---

win = None

stopWatchImage = None
startImage = None
stopImage = None
lapImage = None

timeText = None

running = False

# --- start ---

layout()
```

Comment: Hello @furas , I have edited my question to show the rest of my code. I don't quite understand what you showed me. I am a beginner so I am not very knowledgeable on setMouseHandler ect.. Thank you

Comment: `setMouseHandler( function_name ) ` assigns function which it will execute everytime you click mouse. BTW: `function_name` means name without `()` and arguments.

Comment: Got it, so I can setMouseHandler to start the timer for example, but how can I make it so it's when you have a specific area, like a button? I have a start, stop, and lap button for the stopwatch and each needs to do a different thing, respectively. Would you like me to post the remainder of my code? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: `setMouseHandler` runs function with `event` argument which has mouse position so you can use it check if you clicked in area of button. `graphics` in backgroud  uses Tkinter which  has other usefull function - it can `bind()` function to objects like `Rectangle` and runs it when you click this rectangle. It has also function `after(miliseconds, function_name)` which is usefull to run function periodically and update timer.

Comment: BTW: Tkinter has widgets `Button`,`Label, `Text`, etc. I try to do example how to use it in `graphics`

Comment: I add code with Tkinter `Button`, `Label` and `after()`

Comment: Thank you, but I am trying to make a button I made in Photoshop my button, instead of the default Tkinter button.

Comment: Tkinter Button can display image

Comment: Okay, i will play around with it. I am extremely new, however and do not understand your code, my apologies. I also do not know how to use tkinter and when I try to use it I get multiple errors. I will update what I have without tkinter in my question.

Comment: `graphics` is nice for simple draws on canvas but it hides tkinter which is more powerfull and has more tutorials.

Comment: I have updated my question with my full code since your last reply. If possible could you tell me what I am doing wrong? I would like to try to get this to work without tkinter, although I will try to learn tkinter in the future.

Comment: I try to run your code but there are syntax mistakes - ie. you forgot `:` after `def layout()` - and undefined variable `default` which you use in `getChoice(default, win)`.

Comment: what is `win.yUP()` ? There is no `y.Up()` in `graphics`. `Image` doesn't have method `getP1()`.

Comment: you do `while sec >= 0 and sec < 61:` but inside this `while-loop` you doesn't change `sec` so it will freeze code.

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed that but now I get the error "AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'getP1'" When I try to click anywhere on my win.

Comment: I sad before - `Image` doesn't have method `getP1()`. There is `getAnchor()` to get left-top point, and `getWidth()`, `getHeight()` to get right-bottom point.

Comment: In `getChoice()` you use `timeText.setText()` but you didn't create `timeText` yet.

Comment: I have fixed everything in the while loop, I just didn't update the thread. My apologies for my ignorance.  'int' object has no attribute 'getX' is my error now. I will update my thread with my current code.

Comment: Unfortunately that code doesn't work for some reason, it says AttributeError: 'GraphWin' object has no attribute 'getKey'

Comment: Maybe we use different versions. I use the newest version 5.0 from http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/